# Chrome local storage problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, storage

I'm trying to make default pop of chrome extension act as a settings page

Code so far

[Manifest.json]

```
{

    "name" : "test",

    "description" : "it just works",

    "version" : "1.0",

    "manifest_version" : 2,

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "declarativeContent",
        "storage"
    ],

    "icons": {
        "16"  : "icon_016.png"
    },

    "options_page": "options.html",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [""],
            "js": ["jquery.js", "script.js"]
        }
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js","options.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },



    "browser_action":{

        "default_icon": "icon_016.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

[popup.html]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <base target="_blank" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='spectrum.js'></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='spectrum.css' />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="options.js"></script>
    <style type='text/css'>

        body {
            width: 300px;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .bc {
            text-align: center;
            height: 60px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body onload="loadOptions()">
    <div class="bc container well">

                                <div class="input-group-addon">Refresh time (s)</div>
                                <input class="input" type="number" id="refresh">
                                    <br /><br />
                                <div class="input-group-addon">Max Buy</div>
                                <input class="input" type="number" id="maxBuy">
                                    <br /><br />
                                <div class="input-group-addon">Min Buy</div>
                                <input class="input" type="number" id="minBuy">
                                    <br /><br />
                                <div class="input-group-addon">Buy at (%) discount</div>
                                <input class="input" type="number" id="discount">
                                    <br /><br />

                                <button onclick="saveOptions()">Save</button>
                                    <br />

                                <button onclick="eraseOptions()">Restore default</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[options.js]

```
var defmax = 999999;
var defmin = 0;
var defdisc = 30;
var defref = 10;



function loadOptions() {

   var maxBuy = localStorage["maxBuy"];
   var minBuy = localStorage["minBuy"];
   var discount = localStorage["discount"];
   var refresh = localStorage["refresh"];


    // value is not void/null

    if (maxBuy == undefined) {

        maxBuy = defmax;

    }

    if (minBuy == undefined) {

        minBuy = defmin;

    }

    if (discount == undefined) {

        discount = defdisc;

    }

    if (refresh == undefined) {

        refresh = defref;

    }

}


function saveOptions() {

   var select1 = document.getElementById("maxBuy").value;
   var select2 = document.getElementById("minBuy").value;
   var select3 = document.getElementById("discount").value;
   var select4 = document.getElementById("refresh").value;

    localStorage["maxBuy"] = select1;
    localStorage["minBuy"] = select2;
    localStorage["discount"] = select3;
    localStorage["refresh"] = select4;

     chrome.storage.sync.set({
           maxBuy: $('#maxBuy').val(),
           minBuy: $('#minBuy').val(),
           discount: $('#discount').val(),
           refresh: $('#refresh').val()
        });
}



function eraseOptions() {

    localStorage.removeItem("maxBuy");
    localStorage.removeItem("minBuy");
    localStorage.removeItem("discount");
    localStorage.removeItem("refresh");

    location.reload();

}
```

The idea is for default popup to work as a settings page it goes without saying that it should show the current set values and you should be able to change them. Bare in mind I am new to this and this is just a jumble of code from variaty of projects any pointers would be appreciated.

The question is why is it not working, it doesnt save values and neither does it show default values when you open the pop up

Comment: What question are you asking?

Comment: mention your problem properly,if possible create editor link and write few more words on issue.

Comment: ah sorry about that. The question is why is it not working it doesnt save values and neither does it show default values when you open the pop up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store like

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Arun");
localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Comment: so it would be localStorage.setItem("maxBuy", "#maxBuy"); ? since im getting the new value from basically an html page.

Comment: You can get input value like                                                                                    var valueis=$('#maxBuy).val(); localStorage.setItem("maxBuy", valueis);

Comment: I added window.close(); at the end of save function and the popup doesn' close when you click save therefore its pretty safe to say that popup.html and options.js aren't properly connected but I cant find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to that website, its quite handy. https://jsfiddle.net/uhwx9rgs/

Comment: I'll try to re-work the code with that example thank you.

Comment: Alright it works fine, i have one last question though, how do i make the stored value appear in the input field when the page loads?

Comment: var item=localStorage.getItem("lastname"); $('#maxBuy).val(item);